# Banned from traveling to Romania for 6 months due to violating the 90-180 rule

Tags: 90-180-visa-rules, romania, denied-boarding

I got stuck in Romania after my german visa expired and had to wait for my residence card to be issued, it was delivered to me from Germany to Romania.

Now at passport control I was fined and 'banned' from entering Romania for 180 days.

I stay in Romania because my girlfriend and her family live and work there and I just spend the time with them.

What can I do to help my situation? Regarding the 180 day ban?

In the paper it says that this issue can be challenged at the Bucharest court of appeal, but do I have the right to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: This lacks a lot of important details: what sort of German visa did you have? Where is your passport and where is your residence card from? At what passport control have you been fined and were your passport stamped? What documents did you receive about your ban?

Comment: Without a long stay visa for Romania, you cannot stay longer than 90 days. Even with a german residence permit, you are only allowed 90 days. What reason would you give to challange this?

Answer (score 6):

You simply didn't have the right to stay that long; it doesn't matter what you would 'like' to do. Being 'stuck' probably means you didn't want to go back to your home country, which is what you were supposed to do (again, it wouldn't matter what you *liked* to do).

There is little chance to get the 180 days ban revoked; learn from it, and don't get 'stuck' again. Next time you would probably get a ban for life.

Comment: Thank you, I definitely will learn from this mistake :)